# How to skip the row when no edit trigger in a cell?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm creating a simple application with `datagridview`. Users have the capability to update multiple rows.
I don't have a problem when saving multiple rows in one run.
But my problem is how to skip the row when no edit trigger in a cell?

Because I'm using `For Loop` to update multiple rows.

```
 int rows = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < frm1.dgViewTask.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
     if (frm1.btnMLA.Enabled == false)
     {
         objNPTBEL.reportingDate = reportingDate.ToString();
         objNPTBEL.startDate = startDate.ToString();
         objNPTBEL.endDate = endDate.ToString();
     }
     else
     {
         objNPTBEL.reportingDate = reportingDate1.ToString();
         objNPTBEL.startDate = estStartDate.ToString();
         objNPTBEL.endDate = estEndDate.ToString();
     }
               
         objNPTBEL.id = Convert.ToInt32(frm1.dgViewTask.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
         objNPTBEL.taskname = frm1.dgViewTask.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
         objNPTBEL.remarks = frm1.dgViewTask.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();

         rows = objNPTBLL.NonProcessingTime(9, objNPTBEL.id, objNPTBEL.workdayID, objNPTBEL.taskname, objNPTBEL.reportingDate, objNPTBEL.remarks, objNPTBEL.startDate, objNPTBEL.endDate, null, null, objNPTBEL.eststartDate, objNPTBEL.estendDate, null, objNPTBEL.estreportingDate, null, null, objNPTBEL.rationale);
 }

 if (rows > 0)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Updated successfully.", "DigiTrack", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
     frm1.RefreshdgViewTask();
     frm1.clearVariable();
     this.Hide();
 }
```

and I'm thinking if I have 500+ rows it will loop 500+. Is there any way to skip the untouched cell?

Comment: Using a `DataTable` as a `DataSource` to the grid may help with… [DataTable.GetChanges Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.getchanges?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. Thanks, @T.Schwarz